# IBM Tivoli Reclaim vs Update

Tags: backup, database, datacenter, ibm, tivoli

What is the difference between TSM reclaim vs update? I have accidentally run the reclaim command on my offsite pool? Is it fine to run the reclaim command on offsite pool or is there a bad impact by running this command?

Below is the reclaim Command which i ran on Offsite pool

```
reclaim stgpool offsitepoolname threshold=50
```

The usuall command we run on offsite pool is

`update stgpool offsitepoolname reclaim=50`

Please help me, Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Each time a new back-up is required files of the pool are put on tape.  For each of those files, it exists a older file that goes further in the past that the number of version you want to keep. *Reclaim process* copy files that are within the latest number of versions of a pool.  In other words, those files which are no longer required are skipped.

Reclaiming is so not a bad think : no useful informations are lost.

But, never reclaim volume that have not a reclaimable space below 50% because this require too many write, make a tape out of 2 is good!